# jQuery - Add active class and remove active from other element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery, so I'm sorry if this is a silly question.  But I've been looking through Stack Overflow and I can find things that half work, I just can't get it to fully work.

I have 2 tabs - 1 is active, the other is not.  Once the inactive tab is clicked, I want that to be given the class of active, and the previous active class to be removed.  And vice versa each time an inactive tab is clicked.

Any help would be great!

Here's what I currently have:
**http://jsfiddle.net/zLpe5/**

Here's what I've tried for adding and removing the class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tab").click(function () {
    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
    $(".tab").addClass("active");        
});
});
```

If anybody could help with with merging the 2 bits of script in my fiddle that'd be a massive help too.  As I'm quite confused about how that's done!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tab").click(function () {
    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).addClass("active");   
});
});
```

when you are using `$(".tab").addClass("active");`, it targets all the elements with class name `.tab`. Instead when you use `this` it looks for the element which has an event, in your case the element which is **clicked**.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. It worked well for me, but I've got one concern. Why do I have to double click in other for the active class to be active on next element. A single click would have worked. Not sure if because the code clearly indicated the on click event which I get it. But, My question here is, how could I avoid double clicking for active class to be active?

Comment: @appdesigns if I understood you correctly, you want to avoid action on clicking an active tab. For that do a check "if the clicked tab does not have an active class". The resulting code will be `$(".tab").click(function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
        {
            $(".tab").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");        
        }
    });`

Comment: it works same as below:  I want to be able to avoid double clicking in other for the active class to move on to the next element.                                                                                           $(document).ready(function() {
$(".tab").click(function () {
    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).addClass("active");   
});
});

Answer (score 11):

You can remove class `active` from all `.tab` and use `$(this)` to target current clicked `.tab`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab").click(function () {
        $(".tab").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");     
    });
});
```

Your code won't work because after removing class `active` from all `.tab`, you also add class `active` to all `.tab` again. So you need to use `$(this)` instead of `$('.tab')` to add the class `active` only to the clicked `.tab` anchor

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLpe5/3/)**

Comment: `this` refers to clicked element, `$(".tab").toggleClass("active")` was fine. However you've updated the answer and came with another solution.

Answer (score 8):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab").click(function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
        {
            $(".tab.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");        
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tab").click(function () {
        $("this").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You alread removed the active class from all the tabs but then you add the active class, again, to all the tabs. You should only add the active class to the currently selected tab like so http://jsfiddle.net/QFnRa/

```
$(".tab").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use jquery cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie and then you can be sure the class will stay on page refresh.

Stores the id of the clicked element in the cookie and then uses that to add the class on refresh.

```
        //Get cookie value and set active
        var tab = $.cookie('active');
        $('#' + tab).addClass('active');

        //Set cookie active tab value on click
        //Done this way to preserve after page refresh
        $('.topTab').click(function (event) {
            var clickedTab = event.target.id;
            $.removeCookie('active', { path: '/' });
            $( '.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            $.cookie('active', clickedTab, { path: '/' });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code will remove the current active class to the element and add active class to the clicked element

```
    $('li').click((e)=>{ 
       $('.active').removeClass('active'); 
       $(e.currentTarget).addClass("active"); 
    });
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.