# Functionality like tabs but scenario with appending to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, append

```js
$('.day-col-content').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {

      $('.day-col').removeClass('selected')
      $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
      $(this).clone().appendTo('.selected-day');
      $('.selected-day .day-col-content').addClass('selected');
    });
  });
```

```css
.actual-weather {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .selected-day .selected-day {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .selected-day .day-col-content {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .selected-day .day-col-content.selected {
    display: block
  }
  
  .days-box {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .day-col {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:red;
  }

  .day-col.selected {
    background:blue;
  }

  
  .day-col .day-col-content {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="actual-weather">
  <span class="selected-day"></span>
</div>
<div class="days-box">
  <div class="day-col">
    <div class="day-col-content">
      <p class="weather">
        content 1
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-col">
    <div class="day-col-content">
      <p class="weather">
        content 2
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-col">
    <div class="day-col-content">
      <p class="weather">
        content 3
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

I have scenario where I want to click on specific div and then this div append to another div ( selected day)

and then I want to switch between appended divs for showing selected div (day) (for functionality like tabs).

Problem is that all div are showing and I don't know how to manage thoose selected divs

Does somebody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Make the code a stackoverflow snippet.

Comment: This is a better way to ask a question like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528892/jquery-add-active-class-and-remove-active-from-other-element-on-click Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/mktgnp3e/ or this? https://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/vzx31439/  Try and make your code runnable and it's 10x easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to empty the div first then append the DATA or use `.html()` directly and it will overrite the data:

```
$('.selected-day').html('').append( $(this).clone() );
//OR
$('.selected-day').html( $(this).clone() );
```

**NOTE:**  You don't have to loop using `.each()` to attach the click event to all the divs just use the selector directly like :

```
$('.day-col-content').on('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

**SAMPLE**

```js
$('.day-col-content').on('click', function() {
    $('.day-col').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    $('.selected-day').html($(this).clone());
});
```

```css
.selected-day {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="day-col">
  <div class="day-col-content">
    <p class="weather">
      day 1
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="day-col">
  <div class="day-col-content">
    <p class="weather">
      day 2
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="day-col">
  <div class="day-col-content">
    <p class="weather">
      day 3
    </p>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div class="selected-day"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome, Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm not sure about your styling but this would work as a custom tab version

```js
$(document).on('click','.day-col-content',function(){
    $('.day-col').removeClass('selected')
    $(this).parent('.day-col').addClass('selected');
    $('.selected-day').html($(this).clone());
    $('.selected-day .day-col-content').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.day-col.selected {
  color:green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="day-col">
    <div class="day-col-content">
        <p class="weather">
        content 1
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="day-col">
    <div class="day-col-content">
        <p class="weather">
        content 2
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="day-col">
    <div class="day-col-content">
        <p class="weather">
        content 3
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="selected-day"></div>
```